# How to visualize real-time data candlestick chart for cryptocurrencies?

Tags: python, real-time, interactive, cryptocurrency, candlestick-chart

I'm actually trying to code a small program in Python to visualize the actual price of a crypto asset with real-time data. I already have the data (historic and actual data updated every second). I just want to find a good python library (as optimized as possible) in order to show the candlestick chart and eventually some indicators or lines/curves on the same graph. I did some quick research and it seems like "plotly" (used with "cufflinks") or "bokeh" are good choices. Which one would you advise me and why ? I'm also open to some suggestions of other libraries if they are good and optimized !
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot.

Where you can find examples of fetching realtime data from crypto exchange. Author notifies that this library designed in favor of speed and crypto.
Looks very nice.